# How to calculate the magnetic dipole moment of a bar magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I want to calculate the force between two magnets. In a previous Phys.SE [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81877/2451), I was told that I needed to use the [dipole-dipole interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole%E2%80%93dipole_interaction), but that equation depends on $m$, the magnetic dipole moment of the magnet.

How do I calculate $m$? I found a source that said $m = p \ell$ where $p$ is the "magnetic pole strength" and $\ell$ is the length of the magnet, but I haven't found anything that says how to compute $p$.

Comment: Given the amount of emphasis we put on the electrostatic force in introductory courses I am always a bit amused by how studiously we avoid this problem. I don't think I've even seen it treated. That said, I am pretty sure that one would have to *measure* rather than calculate this value for any given physical example magnet. Once could then compute forces involving two of them to his or her hearts content.

Comment: Hint; a tightly wound solenoid with a metered current flowing through it should provide a pole of known strength.

Comment: @dmckee I have an idea , I already know the B of the magnet , if we have a solenoid with given turns and radius , we can easily calculate the current needed to give us B , then if there's a formula relating current to pole strength we can use and find out about. So , how to know the pole strength  when current flow in a solenoid?

Comment: This question was driving me nuts for a while until I found this article. Basically they show a way that you can measure it. Check it out: http://www.academia.edu/2560530/_Physics_through_teaching_lab_XXII_Magnet-Solenoid_interaction_ Cheers

Comment: mfw i have the exact same question and there is no answer here kek

Answer (score 0):

A bar magnet is not a pure magnetic dipole, but we can calculate the dipole moment by comparing the magnetic fields of a bar magnet and a magnetic dipole at large distances where contributions from higher order moments become negligible.

The [magnetic dipole field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/408052/145491) a distance $z$ from a dipole $m$ along the dipole axis is:
$$B=\frac{\mu_0 m}{2 \pi z^3}\tag{1}$$

For a cylindrical bar magnet, the magnetic field a distance $z$ from the centre  along the symmetry axis is

$$B=\frac{B_r}{2}\left (\frac{z+L/2}{\sqrt{{R}^2+{(z+L/2)}^2}} -\frac{z-L/2}{\sqrt{R^2+(z-L/2)^2}}\right )\tag{2}$$

where $B_r$ is the [remanence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remanence), and $L$ & $R$ are the length and radius of the magnet. (This is just a slight change of variables from the field given in the answer to ["How strong is the magnetic field from a neodymium magnet?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/744212/145491).)

At large distances from the magnet

$$\lim_{z\gg L,R} B=\frac{B_r R^2 L}{2z^3} \tag{3}$$

So the magnetic moment of a cylindrical bar magnet is

$$m=B_r\frac{AL}{\mu_0}\tag{4}$$

where $A=\pi R^2$ is the cross-sectional area of the bar magnet.

The remanence is not directly measurable,  but can be calculated (using Eq. 2) from the magnetic field strength $B_{pole}$ on the magnet axis at the pole surface (i.e.  at$z=L/2$):

$$B_r=2B_{pole}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{R}{L}\right)^2} \tag{5}$$

which gives

$$m=2B_{pole}\frac{A}{\mu_0}\sqrt{L^2+R^2}\tag{6}$$

It is important to remember that although this may be the dipole moment of a bar magnet, a bar magnet has non-zero higher order moments whose contributions to the field fall off faster than the dipole $1/r^3$.  The magnetic field of a bar magnet only matches a dipole field for distances much greater the dimensions of the magnet.