# Magnetic field of magnetic dipole along the z-axis

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

The vector potential for a magnetic dipole is given by the following formula:

$$
\vec{A} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 c^2}\frac{\vec{m}\times\hat{e}}{R^2}
$$

From this expression we can deduce that for a dipole $\vec{m} = m\hat{k}$ the vector potential along the z axis would be zero, due to the vector product. Then we can deduce that the magnetic field of the dipole would be zero along the z axis.

But if we start from the magnetic field formula:

$$
\vec{B} = \frac{\mu}{4\pi}\left(\frac{3\vec{r}(\vec{m}\cdot\vec{r})}{r^5}-\frac{\vec{m}}{r^3}\right)
$$

It is clear that there is a non-zero component along the z-axis.
What am I doing wrong with my reasoning. Is this somewhat related to the Gauge freedom of the vector potential?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry about that. I will try to rephrase my question!

Answer (score 2):

> the vector potential along the z axis would be zero,
> due to the vector product. Then we can deduce that
> the magnetic field of the dipole would be zero along the z axis.

No, you cannot deduce that.

For calculating the magnetic field $\vec{B}(\vec{r})$
at position $\vec{r}$ you not only need the
vector potential $\vec{A}(\vec{r})$ at that position.
Because of the differential operator in
$\vec{B}(\vec{r})=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}(\vec{r})$
you also need the vector potential
*in the immediate neighborhood around this position* $\vec{r}$.
So it may well be $\vec{B}(\vec{r})\ne\vec{0}$
even when $\vec{A}(\vec{r})=\vec{0}$ at that position,
just because $\vec{A}$ is non-zero in the neighborhood around it.

Comment: As an analogy, it is completely possible to have the electric *potential* vanish at a point ($V = 0$) but have a non-zero electric *field* at that same point ($\vec{E} \neq 0$.)

Answer (score 0):

"Then we can deduce that the magnetic field of the dipole would be zero along the z axis". That's not correct because $\vec{B}=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}$

$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}=\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ A_{x} & A_{y} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Clearly, there is a $z$ component.

Comment: If we want to calculate the Vector potential along the z-axis then $\hat{e} = \hat{k}$. Furthermore $\vec{m}\times\hat{e}=0$ and so we conclude that $A_x=A_y=A_z=0$. Am i wrong in this?

Comment: To be clear, I don't want to calculate the z-component of the vector potential. I want to calculate  A(x,y,z) for x=y=0, i.e. along the z-axis.

Comment: @GeorgiosFilios It's correct that $\vec{A} = 0$ along the axis.  But $\vec{A} = 0$ at a particular point does not imply that $\vec{B} = 0$ at that point.

Comment: @GeorgiosFilios If you look at the expression for $B_z$ you will see that it depends on the derivatives of $A_x, A_$, i.e. how they vary in space, and not on $A_z$ at all.